# Relation between value of derivative and 'size' of Codomain?

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem is,
Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected Region Other than Whole plane with $0\in\Omega$.

Suppose $f(z)$ is a 1-1 holomorphic function from $\Omega$ into Unit Disk $\mathbb D$ such that $f(\Omega)$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb D$.

Show that there is a holomorphic function $g(z)$ from $\Omega$ into $\mathbb D$ such that $f'(0) < g'(0)$.

I think I should use Riemann mapping theorem, But I cannot proceed further.
There are relation between value at 0 of derivative and 'size' of Codomain?

Here is my attempt.

There is conformal map $\psi:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb D$ by Riemann Mapping Theorem.

Let $\phi :\mathbb D \rightarrow \Omega $ be a $\psi^{-1}$.

WLOG, We may assume $\phi(0)=0$.(Adjust by Moibius transformation if necessary.)

Then Clearly $(\psi\circ\phi)^{'}(0) =1$

Now $|(f\circ\psi)^{'}(0)|<1$ by Schwarz-pick lemma.

Note that $(\psi\circ\phi)^{'}(0) = \psi(\phi (0))\cdot \phi^{'}(0)$ and $(f\circ\psi)^{'}(0) = f(\phi (0))\cdot \phi^{'}(0)$

Since $\phi^{'}$ is never zero, We get the result.

Seems correct?

Comment: After using Riemann mapping theorem, My candidate is $g(z) = z$. From D to D.(Schwarz pick theorem.) But, '=' can hold.

Comment: Do you mean, $\left|f^\prime(0)\right|<\left|g^\prime(0)\right|$?

Comment: I made a mistake..

Comment: @JonathanY. I add my attempt. If you have time, Please check it.

Comment: Firstly, you haven't answered my question. Secondly, I don't follow how you get the result in the last sentence (which isn't to say there's a mistake; I simply didn't follow, if you care to elaborate).

Comment: @JonathanY. First, My answer is 'I made a mistake'. and second, Since $\phi(0) = 0$, $|\psi(0)|$ = 1/ $|\phi^{'}(0)|$.

Comment: and similarly, $|f'(0)|<1/1/ |\phi^{'}(0)|$ so, $\psi$ is what we wanted.

Comment: Mistake: |ψ(0)| = 1/ |ϕ′(0)|   ->    |ψ'(0)| = 1/ |ϕ′(0)|